# Check to see if file name exists in directory and rename if it does before completing upload?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file, file-upload, arraylist

I am creating a application that allows users to upload an image to the server of my site. But I want to allow users to upload multiple files with the same name by renaming the new file. 
But I don't know what methods to use to perform this check.

I am thinking about trying to put all of the filenames into an arraylist individually and creating a loop to check the new filename against the rest and if there is a match then I would randomly generate a string of letters to tag onto the new filename.

But I haven't figured out how to populate the arraylist yet and this is the code I have for checking for repeats against the arraylist:

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
For i = 0 To arrayFileNames.Count
    If (fileName = arrayFileNames(i)) Then
        Dim random As Random = New Random()
        random.Next(1, 100000)
        fileName = fileName & random.ToString
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next
```

But this code throws the following error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating a `For` loop, you don't need to manually increase the counter. Remove the line `i = i + 1`.

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
For i = 0 To arrayFileNames.Count
    If (fileName = arrayFileNames(i)) Then
        Dim random As Random = New Random()
        random.Next(1, 100000)
        fileName = fileName & random.ToString
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

- The for loop already takes care of increasing i.
- You'll have a problem if you get a new fileName that is equal to a previous index.
- When you create a new instance of random, you'll get the same value.
- random.ToString() doesn't return what you think it does (check the output).
- You might get a very big filename if you keep appending a big number.

You'll have to change your logic (I haven't tested this code, it's an example to help you out).

```
Dim random As Random = New Random()

Do While arrayFileNames.Contains(fileName)
    fileName = fileName & random.Next(1, 9).ToString
Loop
```